# Get value from form in createview

Tags: python, django

I use a CreateView to create new users, but I want to update an another model in the same time. (add the user to a club)

My form :

```py
class SignUpFormInvitation(UserCreationForm):
    club = forms.CharField(label="Club")
    club_pk = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, label="Pseudo")
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, label="Prénom")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, label='Nom')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, label='E-mail')
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Mot de passe")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Mot de passe confirmation")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'club',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            ]    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpFormInvitation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['club'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

The field club and club_pk are correctly added to the form.

My view :

```py
class SignUpViewInvitation(generic.CreateView):
    """
    display the register form for a sportif
    """
    form_class = SignUpFormInvitation
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user-connexion')
    template_name = 'utilisateurs/signup.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        club = get_object_or_404(Club, token=self.kwargs.get('token'))
        return {
            'club':club,
            'club_pk':club.pk,
        }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        club = Club.objects.get(pk=form.instance.club_pk)
        club.clubs_members.add(self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I try to use form_valid to update the club model but this error is returned :
`'User' object has no attribute 'club_pk'` for this line `club = Club.objects.get(pk=form.instance.club_pk)`

Answer (score 0):

In your Meta class, you have not added club_pk in the fields list. Add it to the fields list to access at a later stage. However, I don't understand why did you use two columns club and club_pk. I think one can suffice

Answer (score 0):

I tried both with club and club_pk and just with club.
The result is the same. If I remove all club__pk occurrence, I got this error : 
`User' object has no attribute 'club'`